# passing class type as parameter and creating instance of it

Tags: java, oop

I want to pass a class type as a parameter to a method in java.all of which have the same constructor parameter.and create an instance of that Class in that method.is this possible?

**Update after some years**: do checkout Sapnesh Naik's answer to this, it seems to be the most up-to-date. I have not accepted is as an answer as I do not have a running java stack.
P.S: Give me a shout if you can verify.

Comment: Are you sure you actually "want" to do it? I wouldn't "want" to do it - ever.

Comment: What is your use case which is compelling this ?

Comment: There are valid use cases like instantiating classes from a factory / constructor based injection. Unless you're writing such a framework, you might as well use a DI to instantiate the class with constructor injection.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Using reflection to create the instance:

```
Object obj = clazz.newInstance();
```

This will use the default *no-arg* constructor to create the instance.

```
Constructor<?> constructor = clazz.getConstructor(String.class);
Object object = constructor.newInstance(new Object[] { strArgument });
```

To create the instance if you have some other constructor which takes arguments.

Answer (score 7):

### `newInstance()` is Deprecated.

> This method propagates any exception thrown by the nullary
>   constructor, including a checked exception. Use of this method
>   effectively bypasses the compile-time exception checking that would
>   otherwise be performed by the compiler. The Constructor.newInstance
>   method avoids this problem by wrapping any exception thrown by the
>   constructor in a (checked)
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException.

**The deprecated call:**

```
clazz.newInstance()
```

**Can be replaced by:**

```
clazz.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance()
```

**Example:**

```
void MyMethod(Class type) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
    type.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
}
```

Comment: Yes this is the actual best answer.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use reflection to do that, but yeah it is certainly possible.

```
void MyMethod(Class className)
{
    try {
        Object obj = className.newInstance();
        //obj is a newly created object of the passed in type
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for Reflection.

Your method would look something like this:

```
public void m1(Class c) {

      try {
        Object obj = c.newInstance();
        //do something with your new instance
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {

    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {

    }
}
```

The Oracle doc for the Reflection API is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/reflection/)

Comment: newInstance() has deprecated since Java 9

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can

```
void x(Class cls) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
    cls.newInstance();
}
```

Note that Class.newInstance may fail with

IllegalAccessException - if the class or its nullary constructor is not accessible.

InstantiationException - if this Class represents an abstract class, an interface, an array class, a primitive type, or void; or if the class has no nullary constructor; or if the instantiation fails for some other reason.

see API for more